# Winsock2: When I try to send a string with spaces, the function appears stop sending when it encounters a space

Tags: c++, sockets, winsock2

I've been battling this code all day now, and I'm close to pulling what remains of my hair.

I've got a Server and Client class, and the original goal was for the Server class to have a list of 'Clients' with which it could interact. The entire host of issues aside, I've got some basics working. The Server does register new connections, and I can even send strings from the Client.

Here's the deal though, when I try to send a string with spaces, the whole thing breaks down.

Here's my Send function

```
    int Send(std::string message)
    {
        const char* cstr = message.c_str();
        size_t      len = message.length();

        //The +1 is for the \0 character that c_str() adds
        //this->server is a socket that has already been connected to and accepted by the server
        int bytes = send(this->server, cstr, len + 1, 0);  
        return bytes;
    }
```

On the server side of things:

```
void Run()
    {
        char buffer[1024];
        while (1)
        {
            listen(server, 0);
            SOCKET incoming_sock;
            int clientAddrSize = sizeof(clientAddr);
            if ((incoming_sock = accept(server, (SOCKADDR*)&clientAddr, &clientAddrSize)) != INVALID_SOCKET)
            {
                std::cout << "Error: " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
                std::cout << "Connection occured " << printIP(clientAddr.sin_addr.s_addr) << std::endl;
                int bytes = recv(incoming_sock, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
                std::cout << bytes << " Bytes With the message: " << buffer << std::endl;
                std::cout << "Error: " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << "Error: " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }
```

Here's the weird part:

In my Client's main function, when I predefine a string, like "Hello World" the Server prints it out just fine. But when I try to parse user input with std::cin, the message breaks down after the first blank space.

Client Main Function:

```
#include "Client.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    Client c("127.0.0.1", 5555, 1);
    std::string msg = "Hello World!";
    while (msg.compare("exit") != 0)
    {

        //std::cout << "Send: ";
        //std::cin >> msg;
        int bytes = c.Send(msg);
        std::cout << "Sent \"" << msg << "\"" << "Bytes: " << bytes << std::endl;
    }
    while (1);
    return 0;
}
```

And the Output on the Server:

```
In the Constructor Error code: 0Bind code: 0
Error: 0
Connection occured 127.0.0.0
13 Bytes With the message: Hello World!
Error: 0
```

If I uncomment the input, and type in "Hello" in the prompt, I get the following output:

```
In the Constructor Error code: 0Bind code: 0
Error: 0
Connection occured 127.0.0.0
6 Bytes With the message: hello
Error: 0
```

But if I type "Hello World!"
I only get:

```
In the Constructor Error code: 0Bind code: 0
Error: 0
Connection occured 127.0.0.0
6 Bytes With the message: Hello
Error: 0
```

Comment: `std::cin >> string` stops at the first whitespace! Try `std::getline(std::cin, string)` to read up to the first newline.

Comment: On a side note, your `Send()` code is not guaranteed to send the entire string in one go. The return value tells you how many bytes were actually accepted for sending You need to call `send()` in a loop until all of the bytes have actually been sent. Likewise, in `Run()`, you need to call `recv()` in a loop until all expected bytes have been received. You are sending the string's null terminator, so read until the terminator arrives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::cin >> msg;` reads up to the first whitespace. If you want to read a full line up to the line-end character, make it

```
std::getline(cin, msg);
```

Comment: it... works. In hindsight, I should've tried to print out what the input was. Would've saved me a few hours. Thank you!